# Start an application that is written in .net standard 2.1 with visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, project

thanks for reading my question.

I have a problem; I want to write a program for my windows notebook (console application or wpf or something like that in C#) where I can read out data from my fitness band "Xiaomi Mi Band 3". I spent a lot of time looking through the internet how it should be possible to communicate with this band. I found an API called "OpenWindesheart" and there is also a NuGet package available in visualstudio.

This API is written in .net standard 2.1 and I found out that it is not possible to use it with the .net framework, so I tried using .net core 3.0 or higher.

The problem is that I am not able to create a project in visual studio where I can include this "library". I am really new in writing softwares and setting up projects in visual studio so I have no idea what kind of project i need to create (console application, wpf, UWP??)

I found an example where this library is used and where I should be able to connect my band and read out the data:
https://github.com/ictinnovaties-zorg/openwindesheart-demo

but if i download these files and open the .sln, i can not run the project (i get the error message that a class library can not be started) so my question is: how can I use these files to run the demo application that i downloaded from the linke above? What additional plugins do I need? I tried adding a console application with the main-function and "create" a new instance of the demo-application but then I get the exception; System.InvalidOperationException : You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init();

I really don't know what that means and where I should call this.

I am using visual studio 2019 on a windows 10 notebook

Thank you very much for your help
Kind regards
Kickflip

Comment: Create a netcore  console application and add a reference to the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project you're trying to run is not actually the executable project.  You will need to set the default project to one of the other two projects in the solution.

I believe that solution has an Android app and an iOS app.  You should be able to run either of the other two through an emulator. To set either of those projects as the startup:  When you right click on the project -> you would get a context menu that has the option to "Set as Startup Project".

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/first-app/?pivots=windows) a step by step for a new project though.

Comment: Hello jimnkey, thanks for your answer. I want to create a project for my windows computer where I can write to excel-files etc. Is that possible even if I use a project that is created for an Android application and use an emulator, or is it somehow possible to rewrite this project that it is not for a mobile application anymore? Thank you and kind regards, Kickflip

Comment: You may or may not have to refactor a little bit but I'm sure it's doable.  There are probably other ways but I'm thinking if you want to be able to re-use that library in a windows 10 desktop app -- you'll want to learn how to build UWP Apps using Xarmarin.Forms.  I'm sure you can google yourself, but here are a couple links to start your reading: [into - a little dated](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/02/01/xamarin-forms.aspx) and more recent one within [microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/develop/)

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. If I am right, UWP is also for mobile application (windows phone? ) but i want to run it on my windows notebook. is it also possible to run a UWP application on the notebook?

Comment: @Kickflip, you could have a try and it should be fine in general.